# Is there a way to get reputation changes network-wide via the API?

Tags: support, reputation, api, linked-accounts

Using the [notifications API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications), I can get everything that shows up in the achievements popover, except for reputation changes.
I can use [reputation history](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-reputation-history) for this, but it's per-site so would require a hit per site I was interested in.

Is there an API method I'm missing that would allow me to access reputation changes topbar-style, or are the reputation history endpoints my best option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a **related feature request** for this](https://stackapps.com/questions/4808/get-reputation-changes-across-all-sites-without-querying-each-one-individually). Go upvote it.

Meanwhile, one workaround is to:

1. **Poll the [`/users/{ids}/associated` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users)** (no more than once per minute).  You can get up to 100 site's data in one API call.
2. Record the `reputation` values for each site, and compare with the previous value.
3. If the reputation has changed for a given site, call `/reputation-history` as desired to get more details as to why.
4. Obviously this is not perfect as reputation changes that cancel each other out may not be detected.  (And that's also a problem with the topbar change indicator.)

Sample `/users/{ids}/associated` route call:
  [/2.2/users/7545763/associated?page=1&pagesize=100](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#page=1&pagesize=100&ids=7545763&filter=default&run=true) currently yields results like:

```
{ "items": [ {
      "badge_counts":       {"bronze": 3, "silver": 1, "gold": 0},
      "question_count":     0,
      "answer_count":       5,
      "last_access_date":   1569160287,
      "creation_date":      1466874855,
      "account_id":         7545763,
      "reputation":         162,          //  <====
      "user_id":            6512983,
      "site_url":           "https://stackoverflow.com",
      "site_name":          "Stack Overflow"
   }, {
      "badge_counts":       {"bronze": 5, "silver": 1, "gold": 0},
      "question_count":     1,
      "answer_count":       7,
      "last_access_date":   1568816203,
      "creation_date":      1462286084,
      "account_id":         7545763,
      "reputation":         206,          //  <====
      "user_id":            352714,
      "site_url":           "https://serverfault.com",
      "site_name":          "Server Fault"
    }, {
   // etc, etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @awesome! I'm already using associated in a similar way, but I'm trying to avoid state. It will have to do for now.